# Upgrading drools 5.5.0 to 6.1.0.Final, need help to reconfigure change set file

Tags: drools

In Drools 5.5.0 version we have use knowledgeBase to precompile drools file as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:drools="http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring http://drools.org/schema/drools-spring.xsd">

    <drools:kbase id="ratingKBase">
        <drools:resources>
            <drools:resource type="CHANGE_SET"
                source="classpath:rules/AutoPreRatingValidations.xml" />
        </drools:resources>
    </drools:kbase>

    <drools:kbase id="bindKBase">
        <drools:resources>
            <drools:resource type="CHANGE_SET"
                source="classpath:rules/AutoPreAppValidations.xml" />
        </drools:resources>
    </drools:kbase>

    <drools:kbase id="issuePolicyKBase">
        <drools:resources>
            <drools:resource type="CHANGE_SET"
                source="classpath:rules/AutoPreIssueValidations.xml" />
        </drools:resources>
    </drools:kbase>

</beans>
```

As per this file it is grouping some of the rules file and pre-compiling it.
In Drools 6.1.0.Final I don't see a way to configure change set like this.

Answer (score 1):

The "change sets" of Drools 5 have gone away. As a replacement, Drools 6 features the `org.kie.api.builder.KieScanner`, as documented in the reference manual (section 2.1.6):

*The KieScanner is a Maven-oriented replacement of the KnowledgeAgent present in Drools 5. It continuously monitors your Maven repository to check if a new release of a Kie project has been installed and if so, deploys it in the KieContainer wrapping that project.*

You will not be able to handle this with a simple "reconfiguration".

Note that Java 7 has introduced java.nio.file.WatchService, supporting file system event monitoring. This should help to manage without Drools 5 change sets.

Comment: in drools 5.x, I had three change set and each change set had different set of drl files,so now when change set is removed, shall I configure rules file in different packages? for e.g drl file that belongs to AutoPreRatingValidations.xml should go to package a,drl files that belongs to AutoPreAppValidations.xml go to package b and drl file that belongs to AutoPreIssueValidations.xml go to package c.Can please you provide me example which uses different drl files?

Comment: I don't think that the package structure of the DRL matters. Whether and how you use `package` in a DRL file is merely a matter to handle visibility in relationship to Java packages. You can put all your DRL into a single directory and monitor that, or distribute them over many directories and monitor all of them - in either case irrespective of the `package` used in the DRL.

Comment: You took me almost there, i am happy,  In my case I have total 9 drl files, 3 are validate to use one functionality 3 are used to validate another functionality and rest of the 3 are used for other functionality, now my question is, if I put all 9 drools files in one package then how can I configure drool engine to pick up selected DRL files to validate some set of functionality.

Comment: In this case I'd use three different packages, compile them independently, serialize the `KiePackage`s (or `KieBase`s) and, for execution, load whichever is required. (But this isn't the original topic any more.)